# WordPress RSS Feed from one specific shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, function, rss, shortcode

I want to make function that will display RSS Feed content from one specific shortcode.
Example, I have:

```
[text1]Text One[/text1]
[text2]Text Two[/text2]
```

Now, content of text2 shortcode should display in RSS Feed.

Function I have so far:

```
function custom_rss($content) {
if(is_feed()){
$content = "Custom Text";
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'custom_rss');
add_filter('the_content', 'custom_rss');
```

Ok, this works, I get "Custom Text" in the RSS Feed.

What function will call content from specific shortcode, in example, from `[text2]Text Two[/text2]`.

Comment: If you want to display shortcode stuff only in the feed, read this http://kovshenin.com/2011/snippet-a-feed-only-shortcode-for-wordpress/

Comment: @pfefferle, I do not need new shortcode, but extract existing into this function. I already have [text2] shortcode, now I want to call it's content to rss. For each post, there is [text2], and for each post in rss content of text2 shortcode should be extracted.

Comment: Shortcodes are also working for RSS-Feeds. If you have implemented the shortcode correctly, there is nothing more to do. See the comment of @ava

Comment: I am using shortcodes for all content, and they are stripped/removed from RSS Feed. My feeds showing just title, than comments. No content. That's why I am looking for this.

Comment: Can you share the shortcode code please?

Comment: I am using this shortcode: http://pastebin.com/KYchYS1W and it's content is not in feeds.

Comment: And this code isn't working on your feed?

Comment: <description><![CDATA[]]></description>

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress Codex:
[shortcode atts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts) and [add_shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
     extract( shortcode_atts( array(
          'foo' => 'no foo',
          'baz' => 'default baz'
     ), $atts ) );
     return "foo = {$foo}";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function text( $atts, $content = null ) {
    if (is_feed()) {
        return $content;
    } else {
        return '<div class="text" style="display: block; margin-left: 160px;">'.$content.'<br><br></div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'text', 'text' );
```

Comment: I checked all functions and there is none which should strip shortcodes from the rss, still, with your function I have it: <description><![CDATA[]]></description>. Tried changing to full content in dashboard, still the same thing.